# Convergence of $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac {1}{n \ln n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know I have seen something similar and there is a telescoping trick to the convergence but it is eluding me.

Comment: Use Cauchy condensation theorem.

Comment: Hi Victoria! Using either the Integral Test or "Cauchy condensation", like MyGlasses suggests, you should be able to find an answer. (It does not involve telescoping, though.)

Comment: Question comes from a (weak) Calculus 2 student. Need to use a teachnique available after 1,5 semensters of calculus.

Comment: Integral test might work but  a bit high level for this guy.

Comment: This problem happens to be kind of a classic one for using the integral test, as far as I know. Did your instructor not teach it yet?

Comment: Not my instructor, tutoring student's instructor and no idea since he is very confused. OK integral test it is, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> **We circumvent using the integral test or its companion, the Cauchy condensation test.  Rather, we use creative telescoping to show that the series $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log(n)}$ diverges.  To that end, we now proceed.**

---

We will use the well-known inequalities for the logarithm ([SEE THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263))

$$\frac{x-1}{x} \le \log(x)\le x-1 \tag1$$

---

Using the right-hand side inequality in $(1)$, we see that

$$\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\le \frac1n \tag 2$$

and

$$\log\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right)\le \frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}-1 \tag3$$

---

Applying $(2)$ and $(3)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=3}^N \frac{1}{n\log(n)} &\ge \sum_{n=3}^N \frac{\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}{\log(n)}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=3}^N \left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)} -1\right)\\\\
&\ge \sum_{n=3}^N \log\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=3}^N \left(\log(\log(n+1)) -\log(\log(n)) \right)\\\\
&=\log(\log(N+1))-\log(\log(3))
\end{align}$$

---

Inasmuch as $\lim_{N\to \infty}\log(\log(N+1))=\infty$, the series of interest diverges by comparison.

And we are done!

> **TOOLS USED:  The right-hand side inequality in $(1)$ and summing a telescoping series.**

Comment: Victoria, please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Comment: @chris Neither the integral test nor its companion Cauchy's condensation test is required.  We need only apply an elementary inequality and a telescoping series.  So, even pre-calculus students are able to handle this one. -Mark

Answer (score 0):

For a decreasing function $a(x) \ge 0$, there is a theorem known as the Integral Test, which says that $\int_{m}^\infty a(x)$ converges if, and only if, $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a(n)$ converges. This is the (probably best) way of determining convergence or divergence here - you'll want to take $a(x) = \frac{1}{x\ln(x)}$.

Comment: Maybe $\ln\ln x$ instead?

Comment: $a(x) = (x\ln(x))^{-1}$?

Comment: You need more than $a(x)\geq 0$ - you need $a(x)$ is decreasing for $x\geq m$.

Comment: I got it with the integral test; integral of the series is indeed ln(ln n)

Was hoping one of the cute tricks would work. Student apparently has not yet read the chapter.

Comment: @victoria Well then. No cure for not having read the chapter.

Comment: Yup. I get them all the time.
For this prize, I sent ten sample convergence test examples, and he got mad at me because I hadn't "worked out the steps" to suit his fancy. Then he sent a sample from class which was a root test. Uhh -- OK but there are nine other tests and I just showed you how to use them. Argh.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is use Cauchy...$f(n)$ coverges or diverges so as $2^nf(2^n)$ converges or diverges.But then the latter is $\Sigma$ $1/nln(2)$ which diverges.