# Does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log(n)}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So I know that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}1/n$ diverges and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}1/n^2$ converges. What about the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty1/n(\log(n))$? I'm pretty confident that it diverges but is there a quick justification?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2223275/42969.

Answer (score 6):

Diverges by Integral test, since $$\displaystyle \int_2^\infty \dfrac{dt}{t \ln(t)} = \int_2^\infty \dfrac{d}{dt} \ln(\ln(t))$$ diverges.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

By [**Cauchy condensation test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) we can consider the condensed series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log(n)} \rightarrow\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^n}{2^n\log(2^n)}$$

and the first converges if and only if the second one converges.

By the same test we can also determine the convergence for the more general case

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^a\log^b(n)}$$

known as [**Bertrand Series**](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'll see if I can
come up with a discrete version
of the integral test.

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(\ln(t+1))-\ln(\ln(t))
&=\ln\left(\dfrac{\ln(t+1)}{\ln(t))}\right)\\
&=\ln\left(\dfrac{\ln(t)+(\ln(t+1)-\ln(t))}{\ln(t))}\right)\\
&=\ln\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(t+1)-\ln(t)}{\ln(t))}\right)\\
&=\ln\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(\frac{t+1}{t})}{\ln(t))}\right)\\
&=\ln\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{t})}{\ln(t))}\right)\\
&<\ln\left(1+\dfrac{\frac{1}{t}}{\ln(t))}\right)
\qquad\text{since } \ln(1+x) < x \text{ for } 0 < x\\
&=\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{t\ln(t))}\right)\\
&<\dfrac{1}{t\ln(t))}\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=2}^n \dfrac{1}{k\ln(k))}
&>\sum_{k=2}^n (\ln(\ln(k+1))-\ln(\ln(k)))\\
&=\ln(\ln(n+1))-\ln(\ln(2)))\\
&\to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Yep - that works.

By iterating this,
we can show that
$\sum_n \dfrac1{n\ln(n)\ln(\ln(n))\ln(\ln(\ln(n)))...}
$
diverges.

All that is needed is
$\ln(1+x) < x$.

Comment: Similar approach here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2223354/42969.

Comment: Not at all surprised.